# Maximum size of VMDK to support large NTFS filesystem in guest

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, emc, vmware-vmdk, gpt

I have a need to support an 8TB filesystem within a Win2k8 guest system running on VMWare.  From what I've read online, the maximum size VMDK I can create is 2T, is this still the case?  Will I need to create some kind of dynamic disk methodology across multiple VMDKs?

We do this already on physical boxes with just a straight 8T LUN and a GPT disk in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of VMWare are you using? The [single VMDK maximum size is still 2TB](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2011/07/new-vsphere-50-storage-features-part-1-vmfs-5.html) with ESXi 5.0 and VMFS-5, but you have the option of presenting storage directly to your VM via passthrough or just spanning multiple VMDK's within your guest OS.

```
The maximum size of a VMDK on VMFS-5 is still 2TB -512 bytes.
The maximum size of a non-passthru (virtual) RDM on VMFS-5 is still 2TB -512 bytes.
The maximum number of LUNs that are supported on an ESXi 5.0 host is still 256.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's still a 2TB .VMDK limit even on VMFS5 partitioned datastores but you can add a >2TB RDM (on a VMFS5 datastore) in physical mode using vSphere 5.

Answer (score 0):

2TB did used to be the limt.  However. the new version of VMFS (VMFS-5) in vSphere 5 supports 64TB Volumes.

As long as you have a support arrangement you can upgrade to vSphere 5 from earlier versions

Comment: VMFS5=>2TB extents yes, but you're still limited in .vmdk creation.